# NodeJS Promise all take all promises from task queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, chunks

I am trying to create a function that will get an Array of promises and will execute them in chunks.

here I have an example of a function I wrote that should have accomplished what Ive wanted.
but what is happening is that all the promises are already executed after the first promise.all.
The nodeJS debugger shows that its working as I wished it was. but I can see in whireshark that all the requests are are sent after the first chunk.

```
const reqs = [...Array(10)].map(() => () => axios.post('http://localhost:7000/test', {}))


const handleChunks = (reqs) => {
    const chunks = []
    const chunkSize = 5
    for (let i = 0; i < reqs.length; i += chunkSize) {
      chunks.push(reqs.slice(i, i + chunkSize))
    }
    chunks.reduce(async (acc, chunk) => {
      const chunkToPromise = chunk.map((chunkFunc) => chunkFunc())
      return Promise.all(chunkToPromise).then(async (result) => {
          acc = await acc
          acc.push(result)
          return acc
      })
    }, Promise.resolve([]))
}
```

Its seems to me that all the Promises that I am creating are already declaring themselves in the Task Queue and that Promise.all doesn't really take what you gave to him but all the promises who are in the Task Queue

Does any one have any clue how to handle this kind of problem?

Edit: I found out that on the client that works the same way...

Comment: Your description of the problem is very different than the code you posted, which is making it very hard to understand. In particular, it isn't at all clear that your array slicing is working the way you seem to expect, or what you expect to accomplish by chunking (not spamming the server with a bunch of requests?). What do you mean by "task queue" as I don't see you e.g. popping anything off a stack?

Comment: The best I can interpret your question is that you want to make `n` requests to a server but want to run them no more than `k` requests at a time, waiting for the current set of `k` requests to finish before moving on to the next. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, Jared you are right.. sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three facets here, chunking the Promises, running the chunk, and waiting for them all to finish. Let's create some helpers:

```
// NOTE: works but probably not optimal. I fired this off the top of my head,
// for something like this in production I'd use a library function from
// lodash or ramda or something.
const partition = (n, xs) => {
  const results = [];
  let i = k = 0;
  while (i < xs.length) {
    results.push([]);
    while (k < n) {
      if (i === xs.length) break;
      results[results.length - 1].push(xs[i]);
      i++;
      k++;
    }
    k = 0;
  }
  return results; 
};

// This will make the requests from the passed in array and
// wait for them all to finish. Note that unlike Promise.all
// allSettled will not bail early if you get a rejection.
const runPromiseFns = async (ps) => Promise.allSettled(ps.map(x => x()));

// This will take an array of arrays of Promise generating functions
// and wait for each sub-array to settle before moving on
// to the next one.
const runChunks = async (chunks) => {
  for (let chunk of chunks) {
    await runPromiseFns(chunk);
  }

  return;
};
```

Great. And now:

```
// Array of request thunks from your original code
const reqs = [...Array(10)].map(() => () => axios.post('http://localhost:7000/test', {}));

// Break into chunks of 5
const chunks = partition(5, reqs);

// Run through the execution pipe. Here allDone is a
// Promise you can .then or await somewhere else.
const allDone = runChunks(chunks);
```

Comment: So Jared first thanks for the quick response. Its seems like your solution is working. but it didn't work in my environment.

Comment: After a couple of experiments I found that the problem in my environment is that im using NODE js version 10.14 -> its seems like there is a bug in this version. i tried the same code in version 12+ and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

```
const promiseAllFn = (pollingRequests) => Promise.all(pollingRequests.map((pollingRequest) => callApi(pollingRequest)));

    chunk(Object.values(subRegister), 4).reduce(
        (prev, pollingRequests) => prev.then(() => promiseAllFn(pollingRequests)),
        Promise.resolve('start')
    );
```